# Did Rocket harm this person?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, to retrieve the aether from the past, Rocket Raccoon uses a device to extract it from Jane Foster.  The exact moment wasn't shown in *Avengers: Endgame*, but it looks like Rocket Raccoon ambushes Jane Foster and extracts the aether.

**Question**: Did Rocket likely harm 2014's Jane Foster in retrieving the aether?

I recall in *Thor: The Dark World* that (a) it evoked a kind of self-defence mechanism when she was handled by Asguardian guards (see also [How did Jane survive absorbing an infinity stone?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60648/63865)), and (b) extracting the aether from Jane Foster wasn't straightforward when she allowed Malekith to take it.  I imagine having it extracted unknowingly would be even worse.  Perhaps there's more to say about this.

Comment: I don't recall how Malektih did it, but that device Rocket was holding looked pretty sophisticated, I'm guessing Stark and co made it. Since they were familiar with the stones (enough to make their own gauntlet) it likely was designed to inflict as little pain as possible.

Comment: Remember they also wanted to do it whilst she was asleep so I doubt it'd hurt her as they wouldn't have wanted to wake her and risk being found out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## We don't know

Logic says no, story telling remains ambiguous. Jane is not shown to be hurt in any way during the movie itself.

What we do know is that the creation of this extraction tool was a highly advanced process - during Thor: The Dark World, Odin himself is unsure of how to remove the Aether from Jane. Rocket, however, creates his own completely untested Aether extraction tool and uses it without testing on Jane Foster.

We do know that Rocket is a Tony Stark level genius being capable of knocking up a Hadron Enforcer out of scrap parts and looking at Rocket's track record this is entirely plausible that the extraction tool worked fine first time, exactly as intended however since the rest of the setup was not elaborated on during the movie definitively stating yes or not to whether Rocket caused Jane any pain would be speculation.

The reason there was not much in the way of explanation around these scenes in the movie is because Natalie Portman did not actually reprise her role - these scenes were left over footage from Thor: The Dark World that were re-purposed by the Russos to make this part of the time heist.